# saveAction() in Controller never called (symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony

I'm a beginner in symfony2. (let's start with that)

I got a form which must send the datas to a db. But each time I click the submit button, the page reload herself (I know why), and doesn't redirect to the one that is supposed to. (the page call herself to send the datas, but then need to be redirected)

What I saw is that the saveAction() method in my controller is never called, as said in the title. And I can't figure why.

Here's my Controller :

```
class ReunionsController extends Controller
{
protected $reunionsService;

/**
 * @Template("IntranetBundle:Reunions:index.html.twig")
 */
public function indexAction($page)
{
    $this->reunionsService = $this->get("intranet.reunions_service");

    if(!$page) {
        $page = 1;
    }

    $pagination = $this->reunionsService->getReunionsByPagination($page);

    // parameters to template
    return array('pagination' => $pagination);
}

/**
 * @Template()
 */
public function createAction(){

    $this->reunionsService = $this->get("intranet.reunions_service");
    $reunion = $this->reunionsService->defaultReunion();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ReunionsType(), $reunion);

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * @Template("IntranetBundle:Reunions:create.html.twig")
 */
public function saveAction()
{
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $this->reunionsService = $this->get("intranet.reunions_service");

    $reunion = $this->reunionsService->defaultReunions();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ReunionsType(), $reunion);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $this->reunionsService->saveReunion($reunion);
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Reunion ajoutée avec succès');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('users_reunions'));
    }
    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction($id)
{
    $request = $this->get('request');
    if (is_null($id)) {
        $postData = $request->get('reunions');
        $id = $postData['id'];
    }

    $this->reunionssService = $this->get("intranet.reunions_service");
    //on récupere le restaurant via son id
    $reunion = $this->reunionsService->getReunions($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(new ReunionsType(), $reunion);

    return  array('form' => $form->createView(), 'id' => $id, 'date' => $reunion->getReunionDate(), 'CR' => $reunion->getReunionCR());
}

/**
 * @Template("IntranetBundle:Restaurants:edit.html.twig")
 */
public function updateAction($id)
{
    $request = $this->get('request');
    if (is_null($id)) {
        $postData = $request->get('reunions');
        $id = $postData['id'];
    }

    $this->reunionsService = $this->get("intranet.reunions_service");
    $reunion = $this->reunionsService->getReunions($id);

    $form = $this->createForm(new ReunionsType(), $reunion);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $this->reunionsService->updateReunions($reunion);
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Objet mis à jour');
    }
    else
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('noticeError', 'L\'objet n\'a pu être mis à jour');
    return  array('form' => $form->createView(), 'id' => $id, 'date' => $reunion->getReunionDate(), 'CR' => $reunion->getReunionCR());
}

}
```

The part of the for Service doing the save (which is also supposed to be called) :

```
public function saveReunion($reunion)
 {
     $this->getEntityManager()->persist($reunion);
     $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
 }
```

And the part of the form that is doing the submit :

```
<form action="{{ path('users_reunions_save') }}" onsubmit="return testAll()" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
            {% include "IntranetBundle:Reunions:formulaire.html.twig" %}
            </fieldset>
            <ul class="sf_list_actions">
                <li class="sf_list_action_list">
                    <a href="{{ path("users_reunions") }}">Retour à la liste</a>
                </li>
                <li class="sf_list_action_save">
                    <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer"/>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
```

Tell me if you need something else to help me figure this out. And I didn't find anything on internet about that...

Thanks in advance

EDIT : That may (surely) be a routing problem.
When I write this :

```
users_reunions_create:
pattern:  /users/reunions/create
defaults: { _controller: IntranetBundle:Reunions:create }

users_reunions_save:
pattern:  /users/reunions/create
defaults: { _controller: IntranetBundle:Reunions:save }
```

It does my problem,
But when I write this :

```
users_reunions_create:
    pattern:  /users/reunions/create
    defaults: { _controller: IntranetBundle:Reunions:save }

users_reunions_save:
    pattern:  /users/reunions/create
    defaults: { _controller: IntranetBundle:Reunions:save }
```

It works. But I wanna go through the second path, the one with "save"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. That was totally the routing. I needed to write that actually :

```
users_reunions_create:
pattern:  /users/reunions/create
defaults: { _controller: IntranetBundle:Reunions:create }

users_reunions_save:
pattern:  /users/reunions/save
defaults: { _controller: IntranetBundle:Reunions:save }
```

But I don't really know why because some other pages on the website are written with the routing I was trying to do before... Anyway. Done.